# Deploy Maven Project from Jenkins to JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final

Tags: java, deployment, jboss, jenkins

i've downloaded the last version of jenkins WAR and I deployed it on JBoss AS 7.1.1 Final.
I've created a new job on jenkins and I've setted SVN URL where is located my Maven project, I've built it.
I want jenkins provide an automatic deploy of generated WAR of my project on JBoss, as I installed jenkins plugin "Deploy Plugin".
I've following error:

```
ERROR: Publisher hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher aborted due to exception
org.codehaus.cargo.container.ContainerException: Failed to create deployer with implementation class org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss7xRemoteDeployer for the parameters (container [id = [jboss7x]], deployer type [remote]).
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:154)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:161)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:61)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:917)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1040)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1765)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:220)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:150)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot locate the JBoss connector classes! Make sure the required JBoss JARs (or Maven dependencies) are in CARGO's classpath.
More information on: http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:161)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.java:41)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:156)
    ... 27 more
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:220)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createInstance(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:43)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractGenericHintFactory.java:150)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.spi.AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.createImplementation(AbstractIntrospectionGenericHintFactory.java:93)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.generic.deployer.DefaultDeployerFactory.createDeployer(DefaultDeployerFactory.java:161)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.deploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:61)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:116)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter$1.invoke(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:917)
    at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:895)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.CargoContainerAdapter.redeploy(CargoContainerAdapter.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.deploy.DeployPublisher.perform(DeployPublisher.java:61)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$3.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:45)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:770)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.performAllBuildSteps(AbstractBuild.java:734)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild$MavenModuleSetBuildExecution.post2(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:1040)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.post(AbstractBuild.java:683)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1765)
    at hudson.maven.MavenModuleSetBuild.run(MavenModuleSetBuild.java:529)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:89)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:240)
Caused by: org.codehaus.cargo.util.CargoException: Cannot locate the JBoss connector classes! Make sure the required JBoss JARs (or Maven dependencies) are in CARGO's classpath.
More information on: http://cargo.codehaus.org/JBoss+Remote+Deployer
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:161)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss7xRemoteDeployer.java:41)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jboss.as.controller.client.ModelControllerClient
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClassInComponents(AntClassLoader.java:1375)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.findClass(AntClassLoader.java:1325)
    at jenkins.util.AntClassLoader.loadClass(AntClassLoader.java:1078)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at org.codehaus.cargo.container.jboss.JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.<init>(JBoss5xRemoteDeployer.java:156)
    ... 27 more
Finished: FAILURE
```

Thanks for help! :)

Answer (score 2):

It seems your plugin is not able to find the `ModelControllerClient`. It has a missing dependency on the org.jboss.as:jboss-as-controller-client.

I should recommend using this plugin: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/
Because i use and i know it works.

Take a look at how to configure it: https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/examples/deployment-example.html

Comment: where I must to use this plugin? have I add dependency in pom.xml?

Comment: i edited the answer with a useful link to configure it

Comment: I've tried it but I have this error: java.net.ConnectException: JBAS012144: Could not connect to remote://localhost:9999. The connection timed out